# couple of questions about using Uri.Builder in android?

Tags: android, networking, uri

Question # 1: what is the difference between raw and encoded strings in a Uri and why would it be more appropriate to use one or the other? E.G.

```
  Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder(); 
        builder.scheme("http://");
          builder.encodedScheme("http://");  //vs the encoded version
```

Question # 2: when setting the "scheme://authority/path?#fragment" on a Uri.Builder() object where do ":, //, ?, #" go in respect to the methods that set the various part of the Builder object? assume it's a heirarchal URI E.G.

```
  builder.scheme("http://"); //or
    builder.scheme("http:"); // or just
      builder.scheme("http"); //and then append the ":" and "//" elsewhere?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, so thank you in advanced :).

Answer (score 2):

> what is the difference between raw and encoded strings in a Uri

Encoded strings are ones that are already URL-encoded. Raw strings are not.

Note that there is no `encodedScheme()` method [on `Uri.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html).

> why would it be more appropriate to use one or the other?

If your string is already encoded, from wherever you got that string from, use `encoded...()`. If not, don't.

> where do ":, //, ?, #" go

Nowhere. The point behind `Uri` and `Uri.Builder` is, in part, to add that stuff for you.

Comment: i'll go look at the source again, i guess i missed how it appends the characters for you, and does encoding mean the charset and what not e.g. "UTF-8"?

Comment: @3alto: "i guess i missed how it appends the characters for you" -- well, actually, that's `Uri`. `Uri.Builder` just builds up the elements of the `Uri`. `Uri` assembles them into a `String` if/when needed. "does encoding mean the charset and what not e.g. "UTF-8"?" -- no, it means [URL encoding (a.k.a., percent encoding)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).